# Why didn't homophobic thugs toss Don into the river?

Tags: it, it-chapter-two

In opening scene of [IT Chapter Two (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Chapter_Two), In a homophobic rage, the thugs threw Adrian over the bridge. Don can be witness to their crime.

Why didn't they toss Don into the river?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking, because they were not acting rationally. It wasn't a calculated murder (and to be honest, they weren't planning to kill anyone - if not for Pennywise, Adrian would most likely survive) - they just wanted to beat up some gay guys who "offended" them and, if my memory is right, the one tossed to the river was had more guts to stand up to them - hence he attracted more hate and more severe treatment and landed in the river.

After they've pushed Adrian, they've run out of steam for more fight - the other guy was not a threat to them, there was a risk, that the prolonged engagement might attract more attention, so feeling that their job is completed, they've walked away.